Nesting a random factor in GLM(M) including interactions between fixed and random factors
I'd like to follow up on this post:
Nesting a random factor in GLM(M)
I have a similar situation - Genotypes (random) nested within origins (fixed), and then I impose a treatment (fixed; 2 levels) on the genotypes in a common garden. There are two origins, with 10 genotypes per origin. Usually there are at least 3 replicates/genotype/treatment, but sometimes 2 or only 1 replicate for a genotype in one treatment due to death.
Ben Bolker selected this as the proper code:
glmmTMB(data = data, response ~ Treatment + origin +(1|origin:genotype), family = binomial)
But I also want to know how both origin and genotype affects response to treatment (interaction terms). I'm not sure how to specify the genotype x treatment interaction since genotype is random and nested within origin.
I tried this:
Response ~ Treatment*Origin + Treatment:Genotype + (1|Origin:Genotype)
And also this:
Response ~ Treatment*Origin + (1|Treatment:Genotype) + (1|Origin:Genotype)
The first code gave this warning: "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
Warning: Model may not have converged with 1 eigenvalue close to zero: -2.3e-09"
This suggests that the way I'm specifying this model is resulting in redundant predictors, but I'm not sure how to specify the genotype*treatment interaction since genotype is random and nested within origin.
The second code ran, but I'd still like to be confident that it's testing what I want it to.
